# Custom values in Qt Creator (CMake) build settings

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, build-settings

I want to achieve the equivalent of C++ `#define foo "bar"` but **I don't want the value `"bar"` to be part of my code repository**, and the value will depend on whether the build is Debug or Release.

How can I do this?

NB: I like the idea of using the following in CMakeLists.txt `add_compile_definitions(foo="bar")` but I don't know how to supply `"bar"` from the Qt Creator build settings.

Presumably I'd add a Key/Value pair but what would I put?

[image: Qt Creator build settings]

Comment: Maybe you want: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html)

Comment: I don't think CMake options/cache is what I'm after. I suspect it's more about a `-Dxxxxxxx` option that ends up in the command that Qt Creator uses to run CMake, but I don't know how to put that build option together.

Comment: After further research, you're right that CMake cache is what I need, but I had to delve deeper to work out how to use that with Qt Creator build settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 2 step process:

1. Add a Qt Creator build setting to create a *CMake cache variable*.
2. In CMakeLists.txt use the cache variable within a command.

For your example:

1. In Qt Creator build settings,

- either click **Add > String** setting Key to `MYPROJECT_FOO` and Value to `bar`
- or click **Batch Edit...** and add `-DMYPROJECT_FOO:STRING=bar`

2. In CMakeLists,

`target_compile_definitions(mytarget PUBLIC foo="${MYPROJECT_FOO}")`

(As advised by Guillaume Racicot it's better to apply the definition to a single target, as opposed to the entire project, which would be `add_compile_definitions(foo="${MYPROJECT_FOO}")`.)

See also Qt Creator documentation [CMake Build Configuration: Modifying Variable Values](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings-cmake.html#modifying-variable-values).

*Thanks to Guillaume Racicot for deeper explanation of how CMake cache variables can be used.*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to set the definition using `target_compile_definitions`:

```
target_compile_definitions(myexe PUBLIC foo="bar")
```

To set it to different things depending if it's release or debug, using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) would make those options portable when using a multi config generator:

```
target_compile_definitions(myexe PUBLIC
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:foo="bar">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:baz="bat">
)
```

If you really don't want the `bar` option to be present in your repository including the CMake files, there are ways to define that too.

You can send it as part of a command line option. For thst you can define that command line option using the `option` command, then send the command line argument using a preset:

```
option(MYPROJECT_MY_OPTION "Activate the definitions" OFF)

if(MYPROJECT_MY_OPTION)
    target_compile_definitions(myexe PUBLIC
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:foo=bar">
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:baz="bat">
    )
endif()
```

Then create some profiles:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
        "major": 3,
        "minor": 22,
        "patch": 0
    },
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "cmake-pedantic",
            "hidden": true,
            "warnings": {
                "dev": false,
                "deprecated": true,
                "uninitialized": true,
                "unusedCli": true,
                "systemVars": false
            },
            "errors": {
                "dev": false,
                "deprecated": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "generator-ninja",
            "hidden": true,
            "generator": "Ninja Multi-Config",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX": "d",
                "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "ninja"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "dev",
            "displayName": "Development",
            "description": "Development preset",
            "inherits": ["generator-ninja"]
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option",
            "displayName": "Development",
            "description": "Development preset",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build-with-option",
            "inherits": ["generator-ninja"],
            "cacheVariables": {
                "MYPROJECT_MY_OPTION": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "dev-debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "description": "Build with debug informations",
            "configuration": "Debug",
            "configurePreset": "dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-relwithdebinfo",
            "displayName": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "description": "Build with debug informations and optimizations enabled",
            "configuration": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configurePreset": "dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "description": "Build with optimizations enabled",
            "configuration": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option-debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "description": "Build with debug informations",
            "configuration": "Debug",
            "configurePreset": "dev-with-option"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option-relwithdebinfo",
            "displayName": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "description": "Build with debug informations and optimizations enabled",
            "configuration": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configurePreset": "dev-with-option"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option-release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "description": "Build with optimizations enabled",
            "configuration": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "dev-with-option"
        }
    ],
    "testPresets": [
        {
            "name": "base-test",
            "hidden": true,
            "output": {
                "outputOnFailure": true
            },
            "execution": {
                "noTestsAction": "error",
                "stopOnFailure": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "configuration": "Debug",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-relwithdebinfo",
            "displayName": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configuration": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "configuration": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option-debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "configuration": "Debug",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option-relwithdebinfo",
            "displayName": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configuration": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-with-option-release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "configuration": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow IDEs to select between `dev` and `dev-with-option`, and also allow the IDE to select debug or release configs.

Comment: The key part of my question is "I don't want the value "bar" to be part of my code repository" hence wanting to inject it as a build setting that CMake can pick up. If I'm reading your answer right, "bar" would still be within CMakeLists.txt, is it not?

Comment: (It's possible I'm just reading your answer wrong though. I should have been clearer that I was referring to Qt Creator build options, as I'm not familiar with manually creating a configuration file for invoking from the command line.)

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone I don't know much about IDE, I think QtCreator uses CMake in the background. The CMake filles are still part of your repository and part of your code, so I interpreted that as you not wanting the option to fixed in the CMake files either.

Comment: The first part of my answer is about setting the option from the CMake files. The second part is about adding a command line option to your project build so users and package maintainers can set that option from the command line. The last part is about adding a preset file to automate the command line arguments. With the preset, IDEs can let you select which command line profile you want.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Qt Creator has its own way of storing per-profile build settings, so it sounds like the second part is what I'm after. I'll reread your answer and try it out.

Comment: QtCreator 9 had native support for CMake presets: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-9-beta-released